# My ODP.Net application is crashing when I add a Parameter to a Stored Procedure. It wasn't crashing before when we were using Microsoft/Oracle classes

Tags: vb.net, oracle

```
Public Function Does_User_Exist(ByVal strEmpId As String) As Boolean
    Try

        Dim strSQL As String = "DATA.DOES_USER_EXIST"
        Dim cmd As OracleCommand = dba.CreateStoredProcCommand(strSQL)
        cmd.Connection.Open()

        If cmd.Connection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then

            With cmd
                ' CRASHING ON NEXT LINE. I CHANGED THE ORDER AND MADE IT ALL CAPS.
                .Parameters.Add(name:="EMPLOYEE", dbType:=OracleClient.OracleType.VarChar, size:=8).Value = strEmpId 
                .Parameters.Add(name:="ROWCOUNT", dbType:=OracleClient.OracleType.Number).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
            End With

            dba.ExecuteScaler(cmd)

            If cmd.Parameters("RowCount").Value.ToString = 1 Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        End If


    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim DATAErr As New DATA_Errors("DATA_Users", "Does_User_Exist", ex)
        Return False
    Finally

    End Try
End Function
```

I checked the connection state and it's Open

> Message = "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
>   "Oracle.DataAccess"

I am not sure what else to do. I am migrating to ODP.NET from the deprecated Microsoft/Oracle class.

I think the issue is coming from the Parameters. Not sure how to solve it

```
Public Function CreateStoredProcCommand(ByVal cmdtext As String) As OracleCommand
    Dim Cmd As New OracleCommand        ' command object ...
    ' create command ...
    With Cmd
        .Connection = Conn
        .CommandText = cmdtext
        .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    End With
    Return Cmd
End Function
```

---

I updated the code above to look like this

```
            With cmd
                .Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter(parameterName:="EMPLOYEE", type:=OracleClient.OracleType.VarChar, size:=8)).Value = strEmpId
                .Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter(parameterName:="ROWCOUNT", oraType:=OracleClient.OracleType.Number)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
            End With
```

new Error message at runtime is

```
{"Specified argument was out of the range of valid values."}
```

What is out of range? How do I check the value?

Comment: What is the code of `CreateStoredProcCommand`?

Comment: `cmd.Connection.Open()`  

        `If cmd.Connection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then`  What is the sense of this? If you just opened it why would your check if it is open? If the `.Open` method fails you will never reach the `If`

Comment: Give me a clue. What line does the error occur on?

Comment: I updated the code. I added the check for the openstate as a sanity check for myself. I thought that the state was being closed before I had a chance to run my stored procedure.. The error occurs as soon as I perform .Add.Parameters (i changed the order of the two parameter and same impact). I also explicitly called the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old Code

```
        With cmd
            ' CRASHING ON NEXT LINE. I CHANGED THE ORDER AND MADE IT ALL CAPS.
            .Parameters.Add(name:="EMPLOYEE", dbType:=OracleClient.OracleType.VarChar, size:=8).Value = strEmpId 
            .Parameters.Add(name:="ROWCOUNT", dbType:=OracleClient.OracleType.Number).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
        End With
```

New Code

```
Dim oracleParameter(1) As OracleParameter
oracleParameter(0) = New OracleParameter()
oracleParameter(1) = New OracleParameter()


oracleParameter(0) = cmd.Parameters.Add("EMPLOYEE", dbType:=Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Varchar2, size:=8, val:=strEmpId, ParameterDirection.Input)
oracleParameter(1) = cmd.Parameters.Add("ROWCOUNT", dbType:=Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Int16, val:=strEmpId, ParameterDirection.Output)
```

The actual cause was using the Microsoft Implementation of Oracle Type vs Oracle Type